# File I/O Reading with openCV VC++

Tags: c++, image, visual-c++, image-processing

Currently working on open/read images in VC++.

Some examples i came across on the internet use Windows.h I/O routines like ReadFile...but there seems to be inconsistency in there declaration. ( not that i am challenging Windows..maybe something less in my understanding )

Here's what i have got.

```
//So i have this function to load file
BYTE* LoadFile ( int* width, int* height, long* size, LPCWSTR bmpfile )
{
  BITMAPFILEHEADER bmpheader;
  BITMAPINFOHEADER bmpinfo;
  DWORD bytesread = 0;
      HANDLE file = CreateFile ( bmpfile , GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL, 
                              OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL );
  if ( NULL == file )
    return NULL;

  if ( ReadFile ( file, &bmpheader, sizeof ( BITMAPFILEHEADER ),&bytesread, 
                      NULL ) == false )
  {
    CloseHandle ( file );
    return NULL;
  } 
 .
 .
 .
 return appropriate value;
}
```

Now the ReadFile API function is declared as follows in WinBase.h

```
WINBASEAPI BOOL WINAPI ReadFile(
  _In_         HANDLE hFile,
  _Out_        LPVOID lpBuffer,
  _In_         DWORD nNumberOfBytesToRead,
  _Out_opt_    LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesRead,
  _Inout_opt_  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
```

And in MSDN examples... 
They call this function like this.

```
ReadFile(hFile, chBuffer, BUFSIZE, &dwBytesRead, NULL)
```

Which expects that "bytesRead" is sort of out parameter. so it gives me number of bytes read.

But in my code ..it is giving error message.
    'ReadFile' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'LPDWORD *' to 'LPDWORD'

so i just initialized bytesRead to 0 and passed by value.( which is wrong..but just to check if it works ).

then it gives this exception

```
Unhandled exception at 0x774406ae in ImProc.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation 
writing location 0x00000000.
```

Kindly suggest .

Kindly tell if any code i missed out....including while forming the question itself.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you've copied the declaration of `bytesread` correctly?  The error makes it look like it's actually declared as an `LPDWORD` (`DWORD*`), when in the code you quoted it is a `DWORD` (which is correct).  Also, `NULL` is not what `CreateFile` returns on failure.  Why are you using the Windows API here?  `<stdio.h>` and `<iostream>` are both simpler to use and are portable.

Comment: Hi James, Yeah declaration is wrong...it should be                           LPDWORD bytesRead=0; 

typo..
the above errors are showing up with the correct declaration.

I will try the iostream functions as well...i think u are refering to fread() and other functions....but still can you check any fault in Windows API used by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `LPDWORD bytesread = 0` to `DWORD bytesread = 0`.

I ran your code using:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdio>

BYTE* LoadFile(int* width, int* height, long* size, LPCWSTR bmpfile)
{
    DWORD bytesread = 0;
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmpheader;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmpinfo;

    HANDLE file = CreateFile(bmpfile , GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL);
    if (file == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if (ReadFile(file, &bmpheader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &bytesread, NULL) == FALSE)
    {
        CloseHandle(file);
        return NULL;
    }

    printf("Bytes Read: %d", bytesread);
    CloseHandle(file);
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    long size = 0;

    LoadFile(&width, &height, &size, L"C:/Users/Brandon/Desktop/Foo.bmp");
}
```

Prints 14.

However, if you want a more portable solution then the following could work for you as well?

Bitmap.h:

```
#ifndef BITMAP_H_INCLUDED
#define BITMAP_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

class Bitmap
{
    private:
        std::vector<std::uint8_t> Pixels;
        std::uint32_t width, height;
        std::uint16_t BitsPerPixel;

    public:
        Bitmap(const char* FilePath);
        void Save(const char* FilePath);
};
#endif // BITMAP_H_INCLUDED
```

Bitmap.cpp:

```
Bitmap::Bitmap(const char* FilePath) : Pixels(0), width(0), height(0), BitsPerPixel(0)
{
    std::fstream hFile(FilePath, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if (!hFile.is_open()) throw std::invalid_argument("Error: File Not Found.");

    hFile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    int Length = hFile.tellg();
    hFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> FileInfo(Length);
    hFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(FileInfo.data()), 54);

    if(FileInfo[0] != 'B' && FileInfo[1] != 'M')
    {
        hFile.close();
        throw std::invalid_argument("Error: Invalid File Format. Bitmap Required.");
    }

    if (FileInfo[28] != 24 || FileInfo[28] != 32)
    {
        hFile.close();
        throw std::invalid_argument("Error: Invalid File Format. 24 or 32 bit Image Required.");
    }

    BitsPerPixel = FileInfo[28];
    width = FileInfo[18] + (FileInfo[19] << 8);
    height = FileInfo[22] + (FileInfo[23] << 8);
    std::uint32_t PixelsOffset = FileInfo[10] + (FileInfo[11] << 8);
    std::uint32_t size = ((width * BitsPerPixel + 31) / 32) * 4 * height;
    Pixels.resize(size);

    hFile.seekg (PixelsOffset, std::ios::beg);
    hFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(Pixels.data()), size);
    hFile.close();
}

void Bitmap::Save(const char* FilePath)
{
    std::fstream hFile(FilePath, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    if (!hFile.is_open()) throw std::invalid_argument("Error: File not found.");

    std::uint32_t Trash = 0;
    std::uint16_t Planes = 1;
    std::uint32_t biSize = 40;
    std::uint16_t Type = 0x4D42;
    std::uint32_t compression = 0;
    std::uint32_t PixelsOffsetBits = 54;
    std::uint32_t size = ((width * BitsPerPixel + 31) / 32) * 4 * height;
    std::uint32_t bfSize = 54 + size;

    hFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Type), sizeof(Type));
    hFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&bfSize), sizeof(bfSize));
    hFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Trash), sizeof(std::uint32_t));
    hFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&PixelsOffsetBits), sizeof(PixelsOffsetBits));
    hFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&biSize), sizeof(biSize));
    hFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&width), sizeof(width));
    hFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&height), sizeof(height));
    hFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Planes), sizeof(Planes));
    hFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&BitsPerPixel), sizeof(BitsPerPixel));
    hFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&compression), sizeof(compression));
    hFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(size));
    hFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Trash), sizeof(std::uint32_t));
    hFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Trash), sizeof(std::uint32_t));
    hFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Trash), sizeof(std::uint32_t));
    hFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Trash), sizeof(std::uint32_t));
    hFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(Pixels.data()), size);
    hFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Hi CCU, I have included windows.h only (with other libraries) but it throws those errors...
i mentioned winbase.h for the declaration of the ReadFile Function..i got that header when i pressed F12 on ReadLine().

Comment: Hello eyanand, I added a working sample of the code you wrote. You can run it and see that it works. I'm not sure if something is wrong with your compiler but the code above should print 14 or at least print something for you. Your code had `LPDWORD bytesread` instead of `DWORD bytesread`.

Comment: Hi CCU, yeah it is working with the datatype change..i checked out the datatype LPDWORD...it is a long pointer to DWORD..hence accepting the address of DWORD &bytesRead...my bad..thanks for taking time on this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in how you've declared bytesread.

It should be:

```
DWORD bytesread = 0;
```

Not:

```
LPDWORD bytesread = 0;
```

Read that as "(long) pointer to DWORD", equivalent to:

```
DWORD *bytesread = 0;
```

When passing it in by value, you are passing in a NULL pointer, which caused your crash.

Comment: Hi, ok thnks it worked...now i suppose i should look up at those definitions of LPDWORD and DWORD...i got confused with the readline parameters as it accepts LPDWORD ??...hows that happening??

Comment: TLDR: You want to pass the address of a dword to ReadFile. `Address of Existing DWORD is the same as LPDWORD` in this case. What you were doing was:  `LPDWORD bytesRead = NULL`. In this case, you're saying `DWORD* bytesread = null;`. That's a pointer to a dword that points no where. However, the function wanted a pointer to an existing dword so it can store the value in it. Thus you need to pass the address of some existing dword.